# Can't remove class on onmouseout

Tags: javascript, html, css

my logic is simple . What i want to do is that when i onmouseover over button 1 it shows me colored square but when i onmouseout it disappears but i cant get the disappear part to work,i dont know whats wrong.

```js
function screen(){
    let btn= document.getElementsByTagName("button");

    let p = document.createElement('p');
    
    btn[0].appendChild(p);

    if (btn[0].onmouseout){
        btn[0].removeChild(p);

    }    
}
```

```css
body{
    background-color: lightgrey;
}


.btn__div{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 2em;
    margin-top: 2em;
    width: 40%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}


p{
    background: yellow;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    
}
```

```html
<header>
    

        <div class="btn__div">
        <button onmouseover='screen()'>CLICK ME</button>
        <button>CLICK ME 2</button>
        <button>CLICK ME 3</button>
   
    

    <script src="index.js"></script>
```

e disappear part to work

Comment: `if(btn[0].onmouseout)` if mouseout is truthy, it has nothing to do with events you are checking if a property is set. You are not binding an event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind an event, not check that it is truthy

```js
function screen(){
    let btn= document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];

    let p = document.createElement('p');
    p.textContent = 'foo';
    
    btn.appendChild(p);

    function removeIt(){
       btn.removeChild(p);
       btn.removeEventListener("mouseout", removeIt);
    }

    btn.addEventListener("mouseout", removeIt);
 
}
```

```css
body{
    background-color: lightgrey;
}


.btn__div{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 2em;
    margin-top: 2em;
    width: 40%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}


p{
    background: yellow;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    
}
```

```html
<header>
    

        <div class="btn__div">
        <button onmouseover='screen()'>CLICK ME</button>
        <button>CLICK ME 2</button>
        <button>CLICK ME 3</button>
   
    

    <script src="index.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is there a better way to do this with appending classes via javascript or its kinda the same thing?

Comment: i mean that if i create a class via javascript and append it to the btn[0]..  will i have to use the same code or can i do it without creating a function inside a function?

Comment: can you explain a bit why there has to be  ``` btn[0].removeEventListener('mouseout',remove)``` this line of code? when we have already removed the child why do we have to remove the event listener?

Comment: because if you don't you will keep adding more and more events to the button.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a second function that is responsible for deleting element `<p>`:

```
function screenRemove() {
    let p = btn.getElementsByTagName("p")[0];
    btn.removeChild(p);
}
```

Also, please pay attention to the fact that you refer to the `<p>` tag starting from **btn**:

```
let p = btn.getElementsByTagName("p")[0];
```

This will allow you to be precise when referring to this tag.

And specify event **onmouseout** itself in inside the button tag. Like this:

```
<button onmouseover="screenCreate();" onmouseout="screenRemove();">CLICK ME</button>
```

Full code:

```js
let btn = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];

function screenCreate() {
    let p = document.createElement("p");
    btn.appendChild(p);
}

function screenRemove() {
    let p = btn.getElementsByTagName("p")[0];
    btn.removeChild(p);
}
```

```css
body {
    background-color: lightgrey;
}

.btn__div {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 2em;
    margin-top: 2em;
    width: 40%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

p {
    background: yellow;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn__div">
    <button onmouseover="screenCreate();" onmouseout="screenRemove();">CLICK ME</button>
    <button>CLICK ME 2</button>
    <button>CLICK ME 3</button>
</div>
```